# Why are the preview thumbnails blank when I try to share on LinkedIn?

Tags: amazon-s3, linkedin-api, facebook-opengraph

I have an article on the website I help maintain, that I want to share on LinkedIn, via the "Share an update" form on the site. The possible thumbnail images are being detected, and LinkedIn is receiving the correct urls for the images in question (they are served from Amazon's S3 service).

Inspecting the page, I see that a call is made by the page to https://www.linkedin.com/sharing/api/url-preview and the JSON response includes a "previewImages" field (under "data"."content") which is an array of objects/dicts with the fields "url", "mediaProxyUrl", "width", "height", and "size".

The "url" of my preview images is correct. Copying and pasting into the address bar brings it up. The "mediaProxyUrl" however does not load an image. The "size" field is null.

Using a working reference url (an article on another site), I can see that "mediaProxyUrl" is supposed to be linkedin's url for the thumbnail, and that "size" is supposed to be the file size of the original image.

So, why are my preview thumbnails blank? Is this a problem on LinkedIn's end? Is Amazon s3 the problem? I'm at a loss.

P.S. I've checked my og:image and og:image:secure_url headers, they're in order.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting image's **Content-type** property in S3.

[image]